# manytomany field on Admin List

Tags: django, many-to-many

According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_ordering

ManyToManyField fields aren’t supported, because that would entail executing a separate SQL statement for each row in the table. If you want to do this nonetheless, give your model a custom method, and add that method’s name to list_display. (See below for more on custom methods in list_display.)

So I nonetheless want it ;D

I have models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  names = models.ManyToManyField('Name')
  birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  def __unicode__(self):
    return "something"

class Name(models.Model):

  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
  def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s%s%s" % (self.first_name, " %s " % self.middle_name if self.middle_name else ' ', self.last_name)
```

I'd like to have list with all possibilities

- Carlos Ray Norris (10.03.1940)
- Chuck Norris (10.03.1940)
- Chuck Norris (15.01.1978)
- Michael Sylvester Enzio Stallone (06.07.1946)
- Sylvester Stallone (06.07.1946)

As you can see we have 3 persons in base. Two of them has more than one name, two of others has exact the same first and last name

There's two problems - one with name of field and with ordering.

The name of field can be made using method in Models or in ModelAdmin, but I don't show it because the main problem is ordering, so when we can made a ordering - the name will be the additional result

this would be the best, but of course doesn't work:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  ordering = ['names__last_name', 'names__last_name', 'birth_date']
  list_display = ('names__first_name', 'names__last_name', 'birth_date')
```

Any ideas?

**update**

Now I'm checking the query -> the ordering       `ordering = ['names__last_name', 'names__last_name', 'birth_date']` gave the perfect result, but the received fields are limited to person model...

SQL now:

```
SELECT "aaa_person"."id", "aaa_person"."birth_date" FROM "aaa_person" LEFT OUTER JOIN "aaa_person_names" ON ("aaa_person"."id" = "aaa_person_names"."person_id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "aaa_name" ON ("aaa_person_names"."name_id" = "aaa_name"."id") ORDER BY "aaa_name"."last_name" ASC, "aaa_name"."first_name" ASC, "aaa_person"."birth_date" ASC
```

If I change it into:

```
SELECT * FROM "aaa_person" LEFT OUTER JOIN "aaa_person_names" ON ("aaa_person"."id" = "aaa_person_names"."person_id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "aaa_name" ON ("aaa_person_names"."name_id" = "aaa_name"."id") ORDER BY "aaa_name"."last_name" ASC, "aaa_name"."first_name" ASC, "aaa_person"."birth_date" ASC
```

I get perfect list with names.. But how to set the admin to add fields from aaa_name?

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**

looking for solution I add:

```
 def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(PersonAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    qs = qs.distinct()
    return qs
```

earlier result was 5 rows, but without first and last name. I wanted to have only 3 rows (filtering dupes). As I mention the only fields are id and birth date, SELECT DISTINCT should gave me the result. But the result surprised me very much: now qs.query looks:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "backoffice_person"."id", "backoffice_person"."birth_date", "backoffice_name"."last_name", "backoffice_name"."first_name" FROM "backoffice_person" LEFT OUTER JOIN "backoffice_person_names" ON ("backoffice_person"."id" = "backoffice_person_names"."person_id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "backoffice_name" ON ("backoffice_person_names"."name_id" = "backoffice_name"."id") ORDER BY "backoffice_name"."last_name" ASC, "backoffice_name"."first_name" ASC,  "backoffice_person"."birth_date" ASC
```

which is ideal (DISTINCT has no effect on this query). So now the ordering is finished, Now I need the object name.

Now I have:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(PersonAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    qs = qs.distinct()

    return qs
  def get_all_names(self, instance):
    return instance.names.all()

  ordering = ['names__last_name', 'names__first_name', 'names__middle_name','birth_date']
  list_display = ('get_all_names', 'birth_date')
```

so I can see all names for person, but this is not what I want...

I need

```
def get_first_name(self, *ROW*):
  return *ROW*.first_name
```

But what should be instead of ROW?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after 20 hours of thinking and trying, finally I've got solution. It isn't perfect, because I use extra(), but WORKS just as expected.

First, you have to manually add the columns. According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra, and knowing the qs.query I add this line to queryset:

```
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(PersonAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    qs = qs.extra(select={'first_name':'aaa_name.first_name', 'last_name':'aaa_name.last_name'})
    return qs
```

And now everything goes as expected.

I have to add method get_name:

```
def get_name(self, instance):
    return "%s %s" % (instance.first_name, instance.last_name)
```

and change list_display:

```
list_display = ('get_name', 'birth_date')
```

And VOILA!!!

It's a pity, that I have to explicit use database variables not django, but - problem is solved.